# Can´t login to Umbraco 7.0.3

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have developed a new website in Umbraco 7.0.3, and everything works when I run locally at me. But when I run the website to my hosting, I can´t log in to Umbraco. When I typed in my login and password I get kicked back to the login page with the message: Session timed out. log in below.

Umbraco 7.0.3
SQL CE ( know it is not optimal to run sql ce but that's just me working on the website and it so easy to transfer the website to the web site without having to think about the database)
.NET 4.5

I don´t now if this has something to do with this but I get this errormessage when I post my contact form, that works fine on my local machine:
Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: Can you try logging in with a clean session - clear your browser, or better use a different browser. That error relates to the authentication of the Umbraco system and it could be because you are already logged in to your test

Comment: I have tried several different browsers, and cleared the cache. Techniques at the hosting getting the same error too. It is intresseant is that when I transfer the exact same site to a development environment with them, I can login but get up another login box. If I fill in the data, I get the same box again, and if I click cancel I end up on the login box again.

Comment: Sounds like an auth issue for sure, but could be related to file permissions. Can you check and confirm that the Application pool identity user has the correct permissions on the hosting environment?

Comment: Basically i follow this guid: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions

I'll double check how it looks for the rights of the folders.

Comment: Also check the umbraco log table and the application event log on the server. Both might point you to the right exact error that's happening

Comment: It's hard for me to check event logs on the server because the site is located on a hosting environment.

Where do I find umbraco log table?

Comment: on the database itself, but there is a package you can install to see the log - try this one http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/log-manager

Comment: The problem with that package is that you have to be inside umbraco to view it, and when I don´t get in that gone be hard.

Comment: If you can't get onto the database, or can't see the package it's gonna be hard for you. Maybe get a local copy of the SQL CE database and interrogate it offline?

Comment: I can access a local copy of the database, but the problem is that it does not happen when I run locally so I do not know how much I will be helped by it. I have techniques on my hosting environment that looks at it, but thought to ask the question here and see if someone could directly say what is wrong. Thanks anyway.

Comment: no - i mean get the database from your server back down locally and query it there. Either way good luck

Comment: Now it works, don´t know what the error was. A technician in India solved it.

Comment: Those indian technicians - they have all the answers :)

Comment: As I said - I'm pretty sure it was a permissions error. That's typically what would cause the behaviour you saw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting company had set up the environment wrong, so when a technician in India reinstalled the website it solved the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try upgrading to Umbraco 7.1.1 and see if the problem persists?

I had a similar issue on the initial versions of v7 but its working great in the later versions.